# Does any number, p, have a number of prime factors greater than ln(p)?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, upper-lower-bounds

I've wrote a very silly algorithm for prime decomposition, but I can't be certain that it works unless I can find a bound $K(p)$ such that for any number, $p$, the number of prime factors of $p$ is less than $K(p)$ (counting multiplicity, i.e. $4=2*2$ has two factors). Is $\ln(p)$ such a bound?

Comment: Are you looking for distinct prime factors or do you count multiplicity?  Does $360=2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$ have three prime factors or six?

Comment: So by a bound $K$ you actually mean a function of $p$ (and $p$ is not a prime, but a generic natural number), and that ideally $K(p)$ should not be the cardinality of the set of primes that divide $p$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Six. I'll reword.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yeah, a function.

Comment: At the low end, both $4$ and $6$ have two prime factors, and their natural logs are less than $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count according to multiplicity, $2^n$ has $n$ prime factors while $\ln (2^n)=n \ln 2 \approx 0.693 n$, so it fails.  To be safe you could use $\frac 32 \ln p$.  As $2$ is the only prime less than $e$ you need a lot of factors of $2$ to make $\ln p$ fail.